# Beginner: Monero mining in a rented student bedroom with free electricity

Tags: mining

I would like to contribute actively to this community by mining some Monero or another coin.

I currently:
- A'm not interest in profit just contributing to the community (Although it would be nice to have some) 
- I live in a rented student bedroom and have free electricity 
- Would like to mine with a low hash rate and a low power consumption so I don't affect the owner
- Only have Wi-Fi (although this may change)
- Would like the operation to be quiet

Somebody could suggest configurations / videos / articles for my situation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Joss Bird thank you for editing my post, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at the [CoinFoundry Pool](https://coinfoundry.org). It's a new pool based in Germany that will give you a very good starting point so that you understand how to start mining.

Also the support is good there and they have a very good "Get Started" section: [go here](https://coinfoundry.org/pool/xmr) and select the "Get Started" tab. The fees are also very low.

If you provide the following info

- Operating system (you use)
- Mining hardware (for a laptop that would be 'CPU')
- Hashpower (for a laptop 'Standard')
- Wallet (you need one so that coins will be send there)

they will pre-generate the configuration file for you for the appropriate mining software and you can download the config-file and the software directly on their website.

They support a lot of coins. You can mine Monero but that will in no way be profitable because you need a really high hash rate nowadays. If you still want to do it, you of course can.

If you want to mine something that will give you a visible balance, you could go with Electroneum. It's also based on the CryptoNote protocol like Monero, so you kind of support the base protocol :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of resources in the [r/MoneroMining wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index).

The type of internet connection shouldn't matter. Of course, it is worth checking to see if the university or landlord has policies on mining.

The easiest way to start is by configuring hardware you already own.